# select2 remote source not working

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I'am using select2 version 3.4.6.

Iam having some trouble getting the data to the input field, here's my html:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<input id="assetTypes" name="assetTypes" class="form-control input-xlarge" placeholder="" />
</div>
```

The backend returns te following output:

[{"name":Server,"id":1},{"name":Database,"id":2}]

And the js is as follows:

```
     $("#assetTypes").select2({
          ajax: {
                url: "/assets/getAssetTypes",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
                            return {
                                text: obj.name,
                                id: obj.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
              }
     });
```

I don't get any errors in the chrome js console, but as I type, the spinner just keeps spinning without returning any data.

Any suggestions to what the problem might be?

Comment: You should update to version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `map` call, change the function declaration from `function()` to `function(obj)` and then use:

```
text: obj.name,
id: obj.id
```

Comment: Hi, I still can't get it to work. I've updated the original question that hopefully reflect your suggestions. The spinner just keeps spinning without any results showing up. The output at the Console (Eclipse) from the serverside is still the same as above. The javascript conole in chrome shows no errors. If I put an alert(obj.name); line just after this line: results: $.map(data, function (obj) { it dosen't make an alert. Are the code unreachable?

Comment: The second problem is apparently with your JSON - it's faulty. It missed the quotes for the names. eg: instead of `[{"name":Server,"id":1},{"name":Database,"id":2}]` it should be `[{"name":"Server","id":1},{"name":"Database","id":2}]`

Comment: Thx so much, it worked perfect. Spend hours trying to figure this out! :)